# Can the following problem be framed in terms of linear programming?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, algorithms, linear-programming

So I have a $n$-dimensional polynomial that takes in a vector $\vec x$

$$
f(\vec x) = x_1x_2 + 2x_2 + ...
$$

such that $f(\vec x)$ is some arbitrary linear combination between various $x_i$'s and products of $x_i$'s

I want to minimize $f(\vec x)$ subject to

$$
a_1 \leq x_1 \leq b_1
$$
$$
a_2 \leq x_2 \leq b_2
$$
$$
...
$$
$$
a_n \leq x_n \leq b_n
$$

I know that $LP$ linear programming problems are guaranteed solvable in polynomial time, so I wanted to know if my polynomial is considered a linear programming problem, such that it could be solved in a polynomial amount of time. Thank you

Comment: $x_1 x_2$ is a **bilinear** term. Hence, this cannot be written as an LP.

Comment: If you have products of at most two variables then this is known as a quadratic problem (QP). If it is convex then it can be solved in polynomial time.